# Replace function in a price string moves comma to the left

Tags: python-3.x, csv

at the moment I write a web scraper for Notebooks etc. and want to save the result in a csv File.
My problem now is, when I use `price.replace(",", ".")` my separator got shifted 1 position left.

e.g.:

```
price = "379,00€"
price.replace(",", ".")
print(price)
```

-> "37.900€" in my csv File.
This is the line, where I write it in my CSV File.

```
f.write(product_brand + "," + product_name + "," + product_price.replace(",", ".") + "\n")
```

I don't know why this is happening.. I Hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: Can you show what are you are expecting and what is exactly showing up?

Comment: I want 379,00€, but I get 37.900€. I just want to replace the comma by a dot. But if I print it, this error don't show up. Just If I watch my csv after it.

Comment: It works as expected in mine, are you sure its not something else causing the issue?

Comment: The code works fine here; take a look. https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/FirmAromaticDemos#main.py Maybe you can post your full code so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might want to look into utilizing the standard python [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) package. It will do all the heavy lifting of reading  and writing to csv files for you.

Comment: If I post my whole Code into repl.it, it works how it should. But in my visual Studio Code it doesn't ...Now I am more confused :D

Comment: I added some more code, now the replace works but my csv looks a bit weird https://ibb.co/bRmsf3x. Here is a screenshot from my csv File... Some1 already got the same problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to do a currency clean-up before writing the data to a `.csv` file.

Also, it's advisable to use a `csv` module to handle the file writing.

Try this:

```
import csv

data = {
    "price": "379,00€",
    "product_brand": "brand",
    "product_name": "name",
}


def clean_up_currency(d: dict):
    d["price"] = float(data["price"].replace("€", "").replace(",", "."))
    return d


with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, data.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(clean_up_currency(data))
```

The code outputs:

```
price,product_brand,product_name
379.0,brand,name
```